# String update result unexpectedly toggles between two values

Tags: ruby, string, sketchup

SOLVED - 
it happened on name assignment (see new code below)

cause - attempted to rename to same name so it automatically differentiated for me

solution - use IF statement to see if names are the same

Thanks to Jim Foltz for solution

NEW CODE

```
if from != newname
name = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0].definition.name=newname
end
```

---

Plugin is for woodworking - assumes each component is an individual board.
Select a single component - run plugin.
Appends the COMPONENT "Definition" field in "Entity Info" window with part thickness, width and length (inches)

EXAMPLE:

Component Name before running = [Center Panel]

Component Name after  running = [Center Panel: 3/4" x 11 7/8" x 75 1/4"]

*********** THE PROBLEM ***********

Component Name after subsequent run = [Center Panel: 3/4" x 11 7/8" x 75 1/4"#1]
(appends #1 to string)

It runs fine the first time. If I run the plugin again on the same component it appends the component name with "#1".Each subsequent run toggles the "#1" in and out of the string

Plugin will also update the associated TEXT LABEL if one exists 'and' has the same name as the component. The Text Label string does not have this problem.

first half of the code is original
second half is new code (as commented line 62)

```
require 'sketchup.rb'
module JF
module GetDimensions
    module_function
    def get_dimensions
        model = Sketchup.active_model
        selection = model.selection

        ### show VCB and status info...
        Sketchup::set_status_text(("DIMENSIONS..." ), SB_PROMPT)
        Sketchup::set_status_text(" ", SB_VCB_LABEL)
        Sketchup::set_status_text(" ", SB_VCB_VALUE)

        ### Get Selected Entities.
        return unless selection.length == 1
        e = selection[0]
        return unless e.respond_to?(:transformation)

        scale_x = ((Geom::Vector3d.new 1,0,0).transform! e.transformation).length
        scale_y = ((Geom::Vector3d.new 0,1,0).transform! e.transformation).length
        scale_z = ((Geom::Vector3d.new 0,0,1).transform! e.transformation).length

        bb = nil
        if e.is_a? Sketchup::Group
            bb = Geom::BoundingBox.new
            e.entities.each {|en| bb.add(en.bounds) }
        elsif e.is_a? Sketchup::ComponentInstance
            bb = e.definition.bounds
        end

        if bb
            dims = [
                width  = bb.width  * scale_x,
                height = bb.height * scale_y,
                depth  = bb.depth  * scale_z
            ]
            # Original messagebox - commented out by kp
            # UI.messagebox("Largeur:\t#{dims[0].to_l}\nHauteur:\t#{dims[1].to_l}\nProfondeur:\t#{dims[2].to_l}")
        end
        #   Newly added code follows            
        # UI.messagebox("Thickness:\t#{dims.sort[0].to_l}\nWidth:\t#{dims.sort[1].to_l}\nHeight:\t#{dims.sort[2].to_l}")
        # Added by kp - translated and sorted dims smallest to largest
        #               Retrieved Component Name for processing
        #               Checked to see if This component has already been modified
        #               If already modified then strip off previous modification to prepare for current modification
        #               Modify component name
        # New code - added by kp
        name = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0].definition.name
        from = name
        vpos = name.index(":")
        # The following "IF" code could be improved but
        # it worked around an 'array vs string' error
        # I was getting when I tried a different method
        if vpos.nil?
            vpos = 0
        elsif vpos>0
            tempname = name.partition(':').first
            name = tempname
        end
        newname = name + ": #{dims.sort[0].to_l} x #{dims.sort[1].to_l} x #{dims.sort[2].to_l}"
        name = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0].definition.name=newname
        to = newname
        # Update the TEXT LABEL
        model.entities.grep(Sketchup::Text) { |text|
        self.replace(text, from, to)
        }
        # End of new code - by kp
    end

    def self.replace(text_entity, from, to)
        text_entity.text = text_entity.text.gsub(from, to)
    end
end
end
### do menu
if( not file_loaded?("kp_ get_dimensions.rb") )
add_separator_to_menu("Plugins")
#   menu_name = "[jf] Get Dimensions"
menu_name = "[kp] Get Dimensions"
UI.menu("Plugins").add_item(menu_name) { JF::GetDimensions.get_dimensions }
end#if
file_loaded("kp_ get_dimensions.rb")
```

Comment: that's definitely odd behavior. By the way, you seem like a decent programmer, don't sell yourself short. In general I'd recommend using a debugger like `pry` and stepping through your code, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Please answer questions as answers, not as part of the question. You can self-answer if reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not posting the solution iaw forum standards. The popup suggestion confused me (easily done).

In case it's not clear - I edited the original post to indicate the solution to the problem. For clarity I'll show it here below.

When the new name for the component was the same as the old name the system (Ruby API I guess?) would differentiate the name for me by appending with the #1 suffix.

This was the original code line problem

```
name = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0].definition.name=newname
```

This was the solution - verify names are not the same.

```
if from != newname
name = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0].definition.name=newname
end
```

I can't cast a vote for the solution as it was sent to me by personal email.